# What are Kubernetes Users for?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I'm studying Kubernetes now, and have a question about Kubernetes Users.   I learned how to create Users and how to limit access by Role, but when should I use it?  For example, if a malicious user (not a k8s user, but an operating user) penetrates the k8s server, they can switch the administrator easily (if they can see `.kube/config`). In addition to that, if a user switches his or her user account and forgets to switch back, then another person who enters next can also use the first user's account. I doubt if I misunderstand the usage of k8s Users, but there seems to be no documents about why k8s prepared it. I assume that Users are only used for doing something from within pods, but if so, what's the difference between Users and Service Accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes has a very loose idea of a user. It knows that authentication is a thing, and that the output of that is a name and maybe some groups and tags. But really all it does it hand that info off to the authorization plugins to decide if a given request is allowed or not. ServiceAccounts are a specific object type because they generate you a JWT signed by the cluster, but there isn't a specific User type, that only exists within the context of your authentication plugin(s).